# Gradle distributions repository in artifactory outdated?

Tags: repository, gradle, artifactory

I set up my virtual repository in artifactory to cache gradle distribution libraries by adding a remote repository called **'gradle-distributions'** as [described here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zhhCD5qtocg). This remote repository points to [this repository](http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/)

As it looks like, the stated remote repository is not up to date any more because the latest version offered is **gradle-1.0-milestone-8-bin.zip**.

Is there a workaround for this issue, like pointing to a different remote repository or whatsoever?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradleware now distributes Gradle from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

But I am not sure that's what you are looking for. If you need some Gradle modules to depend on (like the api), you should use `gradleApi()` dependency, as described [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#customTaskStandalone).

If you're looking for other dependencies, you can configure your Gradle to use standard Artifactory remote repositories like `lib-releases` and make sure that Bintray's JCenter is configured as a remote repository and included in `remote-repos` virtual repository.

Comment: I created a virtual repository called "myApp-libs" which bundles together my 2 local repositories (myApp-snapshot-local, myApp-release-local), the remote-repos and the gradle-distributions remote repo. Normally the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties points to distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip but I want to fetch this from my artifactory as well, e.g. http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myApp

Comment: To add this **gradle-distribution** remote repo I clicked on _import_ on the remote repository section and used the URL http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/ Afterwards I added **gradle-distributions** and as it looks like this one points to the old, outdated repository on http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/

Comment: If you need to download Gradle distributions from Artifactory, you'll need to configure your `gradle-distributions` to point to http://services.gradle.org/distributions/.
Once you did that Gradle 1.7, for example, will be accessable under http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myApp/gradle-1.7-bin.zip

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try that later. Nevertheless I think you should also update this on the jfrog repo as well, since I only followed the steps described in [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zhhCD5qtocg)

Answer (score 1):

Gradle has moved the repository to http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: Thx for the advice, will check it. Maybe artifcatory guys should fix this as well -> open bug?