# Gradle distribution remote repo

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Does anyone know how to create a remote repo that pulls packages from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ ?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091031/pulling-gradle-distributionurl-through-artifactory-remote-simple-repository-resu) seems to indicate it's possible, but I haven't had any luck.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384861/gradle-distributions-repository-in-artifactory-outdated) refers to a video with some instructions, but those don't appear to apply to the version we're on (v7.15).

I suspect I probably need a custom layout, but the file names don't seem to play nicely with the parts Artifactory is expecting.

Here is one of my attempts:
[image: Screenshot of repo setup]

and set this in the gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https://<server_name>:443/artifactory/gradle-dist/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip
```

But it does not work. I'm not able to browse the repo in the Artifactory website nor can I execute the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Artifactory as a source for Gradle distributions, do the following:

1. Create a remote generic repository in Artifactory with the URL pointing to https://services.gradle.org/distributions.
2. Create the Gradle wrapper. As instructed in the Gradle wrapper [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper), you must provide the full URL to the Gradle distibution zip:

   ```
   gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url=<artifactory-url>/gradle-dist/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip
   ```

If authentication is needed, you can add username and password as system properties when running the Gradle commands:

```
./gradlew --version -Dgradle.wrapperUser=<artifactory-username> -Dgradle.wrapperPassword=<artifactory-password>
```

Read more:

1. [Artifactory remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories)
2. [The Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I updated my question with more detail about the problem. It seems like it can't handle the flat file structure at the gradle site or maybe it's the naming convention used for the files.

Comment: The distribution URL is wrong. should be: https://<server_name>:443/artifactory/gradle-dist/gradle-6.8-bin.zip

Comment: That was the trick. I was misled by the folder in Artifactory. Thank you!